# Predict with a machine learning model without knowing the actual model values

Tags: encryption, machine-learning

Imagine Alice has trained a machine learning model. She wants other people like Bob to be able to use her model for prediction, but she doesn't want them to know the actual model. She wants the model to be private.

Is there anyway to predict with a previously trained model without knowing the model itself?

Comment: The industry standard way of doing this, when the protection goes beyond an NDA signed by Bob: Alice runs the model on computers under her control, and grants access to Bob limited to submitting input and receiving outputs. Crypto is involved in this access control, protecting the data flow from alteration and eavesdropping, and (in an ideal world) preventing side channels (timing..) to leak information about the model to Bob and others, beyond the results that the model gives to Bob. Lawyers may still be needed to prevent Bob from training his own model from what he gathers.

Comment: And what if in our scenario we do not trust Alice to give us the correct result?

Comment: Ah, we worry that Alice would not run the good model she developed (and perhaps, demoed to Bob in benchmarks), but rather a diminutive one (perhaps to lower her computing cost). An option would be that Alice entrusts a third party to run the model in a neutral way, keeping it unchanged from one run to the other. Variants of that use trusted hardware to replace the third party. If the issue is not computing power, an HSM or even a Smart Card could do. I doubt that alternatives using White Box Cryptography would be competitive with that. Again, practice could use a contract set up by lawyers!